# How can we add the static label for select2

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, select, jquery-select2

In my application I am using select2 plugin for drop-down with multiple select values. And now I want to add some static option to the select2 drop-down.

```
<select multiple="" class="test">
   <option value="a">Illustrations</option>
   <option value="b">Maps</option>
   <option value="add">Add Status</option>
</select>
```

And I am applying multi select, now when I click on add status option I want to do some functionality and this option will not selected as like the option.

And my js code :

```
$('.test').select2();
$('.test').on("select2-selecting", function(e) { 
   alert($(".test").val());
});
```

But `alert` is giving all the selected values `a,b,add`. But I want to get the `'add'` option only.

Please suggest me how can I do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you are missing a single quote after the first test

Answer (score -1):

Try it with this:

`alert($(".test option:selected").val());`

Comment: Thanks holpducki, Then i will get all the selected values because it's a multi select.

Comment: Yes, with `option:selected` you will get the selected value.

Answer (score -1):

Could it be? Or do you need to handle an event at the value 'add'?

```
$('.test').select2();
$('.test').on("select2:select", function(e) {
    if( $('.test').val()[0] === "add" ) {alert("add")}
    //or search value add
    if($(".test").val().indexOf("add")  > -1) {alert("search add")}
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Tom, Yeah i want to handle the event when i will click on add option.

Comment: It sounds like the OP is using an older version of Select2, so this would need to be `select2-selecting` with the same logic.